# Curve animation with Geometry Node

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I made a mobile hand tied to the body by a chain.
When you move your hand, this chain can be made longer or shorter.

[image]

Moving the hand...

[image]

The GN I use.

Now I need to make it look like the hand chain is fixed and the chain comes out from inside the body.
Any idea how to do it?

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I did it work.

[image]

The secret is that you have to move the end of the line so that the animation is realistic.

[image]

L1-> The original line between the body and the hand

L2-> The line between the hand and the new position inside the body

marked in green-> the calculation of the new position inside the body

[image]

Detail of how it works :D

Comment: nice one!!!! +1